# Where to look for a BIOS update for an Intel 855GM chipset laptop?

Tags: laptop, drivers, bios, motherboard, clevo

I have a Clevo Zeus laptop, model M3CW, with an Intel motherboard, chipset 855GM (Montara-GM). It has a BIOS by Insyde Software and/or SystemSoft, from December of 1999...

Naturally I'm not looking for a brand-new BIOS, but I was hoping maybe a newer one was released that supports booting off of a USB, which would really be helpful.

Now, Clevo still exists, and has a [page for locating drivers and BIOS updates](https://clevo-computer.com/en/support-drivers/) - but I failed to find anything through there. Insyde software [also exists](https://www.insyde.com/), but don't seem to offer BIOS updates directly.

Is there anywhere I could look, or is this totally hopeless?

Comment: Clevo no longer has you model and bios download available, here are the only 2 models they offer. You might contact clevo support>>>>https://my.hidrive.com/share/yze8mg-wf8#$/BIOS%20and%20EC%20Firmware/CLEVO/M_Series

Answer (score 3):

It appears that laptop is from 20 years ago (at least when new).

It is very difficult to find BIOS updates for any machine 10 years old or more.

From 10 down to 5 years, the manufacturer's support site may have BIOS updates that were current at the time. Some manufacturers keep these files, some take them off the site. No particular user rule here.

Five years and newer, BIOS updates are normally available.

I would say that for your laptop (20 years) there would not be any hope of a BIOS update for that Clevo machhine.

Comment: Well, if the BIOS is from 22 years ago, naturally the laptop is not much newer... here's to hoping I can find a BIOS anyway :-(

Comment: I only use BIOS from the manufacturer (3rd party BIOS can brick a machine) so I do not suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Intel® Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html) (Intel® DSA).  I have had some luck with it being able to find older firmware and drivers that were no longer available on the website.

Comment: "Note: This application is supported on Microsoft Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows® 10"